# Is it possible to use WinRM on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell

My question is if WinRM can be install on a Windows 10 because on the page says:

**Installing WinRM**

If WinRM is not already installed with your operating system you can find it in the following downloads.

Note  When choosing a download, carefully review the System Requirements on the download page for both OS and application compatibility.
•Windows Management Framework 4.0
•Windows Management Framework 3.0
•Windows PowerShell 2.0 and WinRM 2.0 for Windows Server 2008
•Windows PowerShell 2.0 and WinRM 2.0 for Windows Server 2008 x64 Edition
•Update for Windows Server 2003 (KB968930)
•Update for Windows Server 2003 x64 Edition (KB968930)
•Windows PowerShell 2.0 and WinRM 2.0 for Windows Vista
•Windows PowerShell 2.0 and WinRM 2.0 for Windows Vista for x64-based Systems

Comment: Have you tried to simply install it?

Comment: Which "page" are you seeing this on exactly?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7):

Powershell 5.0 Production Preview is already included in Windows 10.  To activate its remote management features, run `WinRm qc` as with previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

> **Carefully review the System Requirements on the download page for both OS and application compatibility.**

Clicking the first link, Windows Management Framework 4.0, and you see it does not list Windows 10 on the list.  It is not officially supported.